# unexpected token android studio popup window

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm learning to create a simple drawing app for kids, And I'm having trouble with the code in the **MainActivity**

It says unexpected token or missing ';'

here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV9wb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't declare methods inside method.
Put your `public void ShowPopup()`outside the method and it will be good